# hook object in error handler feather js

Tags: javascript, node.js, feathersjs

I have the following situation, i have a middleware that add a flag when a user is logging

```
//if some situation happend
req.feathers.isAuthenticated = true;
//else
req.feathers.isAuthenticated = false;
next();
```

and i have a hook that check if a user is already logged in some services

```
myService.before({
        create(hook, next) {
            if (!hook.params.isAuthenticated) {
                throw new Error('AccessDenied');
            }
            next();
        }
    });
```

this work as expected, the problem is on the error handler, when i add a simple error handler to the end of my app

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
        if (isDev) {
            console.error(err);
        }
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.json(err);
    });
```

The err object is the entire hook object, that is an instance of Error too

i just want to get the error that a throw before on the hook, i try calling `next(err)` on the hook but this not work.

Some one can help me with this please?

### EDIT

I would like to not delete the hook property on my error handler

Answer (score 0):

When you call `next(error)` you also have to return at the same time so that `next` isn't called again:

```
myService.before({
    create(hook, next) {
        if (!hook.params.isAuthenticated) {
            return next(new Error('AccessDenied'));
        }
        next();
    }
});
```

If that also does not work please [file an issue in feathers-hooks](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-hooks/issues/new).